# How is the product $c_I \alpha^I$ defined?

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation, tensor-products, tensors, exterior-algebra

[image]

**My Doubt:-**

The author had pointed out the notations used by him. I have put that in a box. In the Proposition 3.29, the author used the notation for proving linear independence using $\sum c_{I}\alpha^{I}$. According to the paragraph in the box $c_I=(c_{i_1},...,c_{i_k})$ and $\alpha^I=\alpha_{i_1}\wedge ... \wedge \alpha_{i_k}$. On contradictory to the notation mentioned in the box auther had written $C_I \in \mathbb R$. **How does the product $c_I \alpha^I$ defined?**  From Diego's answer. I have one more doubt. **How can I expand the summation?**  For example, if the summation is like $\sum_{k=1}^n a_ic^i$. Then, without any confusion, I can expand it as $a_1c^1+...+a_nc^n$. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here $c_I$ isn't a tuple, but a number associated with the multi-index $I$. He specifically says so at "$c_I \in \mathbb{R}$".

Comment: How does the product $c_Iα^I$ defined?

Comment: Now I got one more doubt, How would the sum look like?

Comment: Is it like $\sum c_I\alpha^I=\sum_{i_1}\sum_{i_2}\sum_{i_3}...\sum_{i_k}c_{i_1,i_2,...,i_k}\alpha^{i_1}\wedge \alpha^{i_2}...\wedge \alpha^{i_k}$?

Comment: ....yes........